# Apache CXF 2 Web Services - Custom Service Location

Tags: cxf

I have a web service which works fine. I'm trying to build a client to consume this service.

One constraint that I have is that my call has to go via a proxy server for logging (third party hosting  provider). My problem is that I can specify the proxy as the WSDL location and that works fine. The resulting WSDL that is returned specifies the original service address:

I have configures my WSDL location at the proxy:

```
http://[proxy ip address]/csp/sql/ws.Booking.BookingService2.cls?wsdl=1
```

The WSDL shows:

```
    <service name="Booking">
    <port name="BookingSoap" binding="s0:BookingSoap">
    <soap:address      location="https://alpha2.premier.com:443/
        csp/sql/ws.Booking.BookingService2.cls"/>
    </port>
    </service>
```

I want to call this service using the proxy address (192.168.98.45).

Does anyone have an idea how to call a custom service location? In the generated CXF code I can specify a WSDL location and a service name but not service location.

Thanks in advance.

Al

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find a/the solution for this.

I changed the ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY on the binding provider or the port. Here is my code to instantiate the web service that was generated by CXF:

`com.micro.bartws.booking.Booking ss = new com.micro.bartws.booking.Booking(wsdl);

    BookingSoap port = ss.getBookingSoap();
    /* Set NEW Endpoint Location */
    String endpointURL = hubProperties.getProperty("intouchservicelocation");
    BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider)port;
    bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, endpointURL);`

So the WSDL is imported and afgter we change the End point. IT works a treat.

Thanks